# High performance way to get current time in Ruby MRI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, time, profiling

I am optimizing a performance-sensitive TTL cache. The profiler says that about 25% of the time is spent in `Time.now` and `Time#to_f` which are used for time-to-live calculations.

Is there a reliable way to get the current time in Ruby MRI in a simple numeric form (at any granularity) as opposed to as a fancy `Time` object?

Comment: A quick look at `time.c` suggests that `Time` is pretty thin if you're just doing `Time.now.to_f`. Maybe try writing your own C extension that just grabs a time value from a system call and converts it to a Ruby number.

Comment: Are you profiling the cache invalidation system on its own? Do you have a benchmark target for that specific component? You may be focusing energy on the wrong component. Time.now with a float comparison should be capable of assessing tens of thousands of cache TTLs for invalidation per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

It's really not clear from your question what sort of performance you really need, or why your code can't deliver that level of performance. MRI is reasonably performant for most use cases. If you have a special use case, and none of the suggestions below work for you, then you may want to revisit the assumptions in your code or decide whether the Ruby interpreter is really the right tool for a job that requires performance in the microsecond or nanosecond range.

### Benchmarking Time

Ruby doesn't typically sport the fastest code execution, but it's usually "fast enough." On my system, MRI returns 1,000 [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html) objects in ~2ms on average. For example, MRI reports:

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.measure do 1_000.times { t = Time.now.to_f } end
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00000000be2f30
 @cstime=0.0,
 @cutime=0.0,
 @label="",
 @real=0.001831756,
 @stime=0.0,
 @total=0.0,
 @utime=0.0>
```

### Some Options to Consider

I consistently get benchmark times that fall within the microsecond range at roughly `200.times`. That suggests a few things worth considering:

1. Reducing the number of times you poll may help.
2. Using sockets or pipes to feed data from some faster process into Ruby might be a useful approach.
3. You might want Ruby to spawn a background process that runs at C speed.
4. You can always write your own native extensions.

In other words, you might be able to rethink your problem so that the Ruby portions are less time-sensitive. Ruby has a lot of features that enable it to communicate with other processes and applications, and using interprocess communication may help you to perform needful actions asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, I switched to expiring every N operations and the Time performance issue went away.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're on a Unixish system (Linux or OSX) you could do something like this:

```
time = `date +%s`.squish.to_i
```

Comment: This is generally slower than native Ruby, as it needs to exec a process each time through the loop.